# How to determine whether browser provides hardware acceleration for HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, hardware-acceleration, html5-canvas

Is there any way to determine whether the browser is using hardware acceleration for the rendering of an HTML5 canvas?  This would be useful for enabling/disabling certain expensive features.

Comment: I'm guessing no, and the only way to tell would be a quick benchmark and only enable the feature if the benchmark performs above a certain level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently, it's not possible](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/3d/css/#toc-featuredetection).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Start Safari with this command:
CA_COLOR_OPAQUE=1 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari